# Authentication with HTTPHeader field using RESTful WebService

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, authentication, rest

I am making a request to my RESTful web service using ASIHTTPRequest to get the JSON data and i want to send my credential/authentication to the web service through HTTPHeader field.

Is there any way i can send or its the same way that we can set the valueForHTTPHeaderField for NSURLRequest ?

Answer (score 1):

Another common solution is to use AFNetworking library who permits developer to escape from those problems https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Well thanks for answering but still i am not convince with AFNetworking because it use the NSMutableURLRequest/NSURLRequest and which is why i asked in my question that can we send the authentication in HTTP heder as wrapper as SOAP does.

Comment: Authentification in HTTP header is a built in feature of AFNetworking. Check it out at this address http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:

Comment: Thanks @gsempe, let me try with AFNetworking, but i will see whether we can do the same with ASIHTTP.